# convert 12 hour clock to 24 hour time in sparklyr

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark, sparklyr

Im trying to convert the following to a 24 hour time using sparklyr:

```
2021-05-18 9:00:00 PM
```

My expected outcome: 2021-05-18 21:00:00

I have tried:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(datetime_24 = to_timestamp("datetime_12", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))

data %>% 
  mutate(datetime_24 = to_date("datetime_12", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

Both result in NULLs.

I tried the following as a starting point and got this error

```
data %>%
  mutate(datetime_24 = unix_timestamp(datetime_12, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

> You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail
> to parse '2021-05-18 9:00:00 PM' in the new parser. You can set
> spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior
> before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid
> datetime string.

I also tried the following in pyspark but got a similar error:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, col

df_time = spark.table("data")

df_time_new = df_time.withColumn('datetime_24', \
             from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(('datetime_12')), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Error:

> You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail
> to parse '2021-05-18 9:00:00 PM' in the new parser. You can set
> spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior
> before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid
> datetime string. Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-05-18
> 9:00:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY as shown below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

After this, you should not get the error while parsing datetime.

Since there are some changes related to datetime parser in spark v3.0 ([Read here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine)), you are getting that error.

Read datetime patterns [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). According to this you can use pattern 'a' for PM or AM parsing.

```
to_date("datetime_12", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but do you know what the correct specification is for the new spark 3.0?

Comment: Updated the answer, Please check.